# Qual a diferença entre DAO e Repository?

Tags: design-pattern, engenharia-de-software

Qual a diferença entre `DAO` e `Repository`?

Ambas são muito parecidas, mas em qual caso é melhor usar uma ou a outra?

*Gostaria de código de exemplos.*

Comment: Pelo minha experiencia em C#, a unica diferença é a nomenclatura mesmo, ambas as camadas (Padrões de desenvolvimento) eram responsáveis pela persistência dos dados. Sendo que a sigla DAO significa(Data Access Object).

Comment: @Rod fiz um comentário abaixo que acho relevante. Estou formulando uma resposta sobre o assunto para a pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101692/101 e considero a outra resposta bem melhor, apesar de não deixar tão claro a diferença. Se eu conseguir pensar em alguma coisa, eu dou uma resposta. Não estou dizendo que deva fazer alguma coisa, apenas o alerta. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12927/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-dao-e-repository?rq=1#comment211690_81151

Comment: Depois de pesquisar sobre cheguei a conclusão que é mais semântico, conceitual. No máximo tem umas regrinhas do que pode fazer ou não em cada um. No fundo eles servem para mesma coisa e funcionam de forma quase idêntica. Então a resposta Achilles Froes junto com seu comentário esclarecendo está correta. O que certamente está errado é falar em regra de negócio quando o mecanismo é apenas o acesso aos dados. Não vou dizer que a resposta aceita chega estar errada, mas ela é confusa e não exemplifica bem como eles funcionam.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

O objetivo é o mesmo: **Servir de abstração para persistir os dados.**

Existe apenas uma diferença no seu modo de uso:

**Um repositório está vinculado à regra de negócio da aplicação** e está associado ao agregado dos seus objetos de negócio e retorna objetos de domínio que representam esses dados.

Já **o DAO (*Data Access Object*) a principio tem o seu escopo limitado na captura e persistência dos dados de um objeto DTO (*Data Transfer Object*) que representa um registro da base de dados**, consequentemente ele transmite apenas o mundo físico relacional da base de dados e **não representa o mini-mundo real do negócio da sua aplicação.**

Repository: **Avaliacao** é regra de negócio, engloba tudo sobre essa regra, **retornando objetos de domínio do negócio**

```all
class AvaliacaoRepository
{
     public List<Aluno> AlunosAvaliados();
     public List<Gerente> GerentesAvaliados();
     public List<Avaliacao> TodasAvaliacoes();
     public List<Avaliacao> AvaliacoesEmAguardo();
}
```

DAO: **Avaliacao / Usuario são Tabelas** e suas funções retornam objetos (DTO) que representam os registros do banco de dados.

```all
class AvaliacaoDAO 
{
     public List<DTOAvaliacao> TodasAvaliacoes();
     public List<DTOAvaliacao> AvaliacoesEmAguardo();
}

class UsuarioDAO 
{
     public List<DTOUsuario> AlunosAvaliados();
     public List<DTOUsuario> GerentesAvaliados();
}
```

Comment: Ótima abordagem, não conhecia essa diferença de escopo.

Comment: Ou seja, DAO é burro e Repositório é inteligente. =D

Comment: No Entity Framework, DAO seriam as implementações de `DbContext` e afins? Se for, então posso dizer que esses padrões não são mutuamente exclusivos, sendo possível implementar o padrão de repositório, sobre o padrão DAO... seria isso?

Comment: @MiguelAngelo, de fato a aplicabilidade de ambos os modelos é valida só dependendo da circunstância. Desta forma pode ser mais inteligente para um determinado projeto usar uma abordagem burra e vice-versa. Falo isso pois uma abordagem de Repositório (DDD) demanda mais abstração e mais trabalho, sendo mais recomendada para projetos maiores com recursos mais seniores :)

Comment: @MiguelAngelo isso, o EF é um ORM que adianta grande parte do processo de criação dos `DAOs` e `DTOs`. Desta forma é bem aceitável que o seu Repository use o EF para persistir e gerar os objetos/agregados de domínio contextualizados.

Comment: Humm... já sabia o que significava DAO, mas nunca tinha me atentado sobre o que realmente era esse padrão. Essa pergunta, e essa resposta (+comentários) me foram reveladoras. =D

Comment: Breve, bem explicado e em português. Perfeito!

Comment: Sua resposta talvez esteja excessivamente conscisa, causando alguma confusão para quem não tem muito background com o conceito de agregados de entidades, e talvez você queira detalhá-la melhor. Por exemplo: de que maneira exatamente o repositório está "vinculado" às regras de negócio? Outro ponto: uma *AvaliacaoRepository* retornar outros objetos que não Avaliações pode até fazer sentido em algum contexto, mas é um exemplo ruim pois a natureza básica de um repo, como você mesmo disse, é retornar agregados a partir da sua entidade raiz. Ou seja: o repo mais básico só retorna 1 tipo de entidade.

Comment: @Caffé, sua analise é persistente, o repósito está vinculado a regra de negocio "Avaliação" e não obrigatoriamente ao objeto de domínio Avaliação, portanto tudo que estiver associado à Avaliação é passível de ser informado ou retornado pelo repositório, sem que você seja forçado a criar N repositórios para N domínios que existam. O modelo de 1-1 Repositorio-Dominio é muito usado por conta da facilidade dos genéricos, mas muitos dominios podem estar associados a uma regra de negocio. (Aluno, Professor, Sala de Aula, Colégio, etc -> Avaliacao)

Comment: Sua resposta está correta desde que você não adicione a ela este último comentário. Embora eu a tenha julgado correta, algumas pessoas acharam sua resposta confusa talvez porque você tenha imprimido nela, de um jeito que me escapou, este conceito do seu último comentário, o qual está bastante equivocado e misturando conceitos.

Comment: @Caffé Vou ser mais objetivo, em vez de e colocar os metodos espalhados em cada Repositorio (Professor, Gerente, Sala de Aula, Colegio), ela fica centralizada esses ficam no repositorio de Avaliação (Regra de negocio).

Answer (score 49):

> *Aviso: decidi arriscar uma resposta pois achei as demais confusas ou abstratas, dando margem a diferentes interpretações sobre os padrões.*

## TL;DR

DAO e Repository são dois padrões de projetos importantes, cujos propósitos tem uma pequena área de intersecção. Porém, como veremos abaixo, eles diferem tanto em seus objetos, quanto em sua origem e implementação.

DAOs lidam diretamente com a fonte de dados e abstraem as operações realizadas nela. Repositórios provêm uma interface para tratar o armazenamento e recuperação de entidades do domínio como uma coleção.

## DAO

Um [*Data Access Object*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) (Objeto de Acesso a Dados) é um objeto que provê uma interface abstraindo um banco de dados ou algum outro mecanismo de persistência externo à aplicação.

Objetivos:

1. Encapsulamento: não expor detalhes da fonte de dados para o resto da aplicação
2. Princípio da responsabilidade única: ser o único lugar que trabalha com SQL ou dialeto específico daquela fonte de dados
3. Satisfazer necessidades específicas da fonte de dados: mapear devidamente as estruturas de dados ou objetos da aplicação de acordo com os tipos e estruturas específicas da fonte de dados

Exemplo:

```
interface ClienteDao {
    void incluir(Cliente)
    void atualizar(Cliente)
    void atualizarUltimoAcesso(Integer,Date) //atualiza um campo
    Cliente recuperar(Integer)
    Cliente[] listarPorNome(String)
    ...
}
```

Em resumo, um método de um DAO segue o modelo:

```
umMetodoQualquerQueAbstraiUmaQueryEspecifica(ParametrosDaQuery)
```

Geralmente, cada método de um DAO executa uma única operação de leitura ou escrita no banco de dados.

## Repository

Um [*Repository*](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) (Repositório) é um objeto que isola os *objetos ou entidades do domínio* do *código que acessa o banco de dados*.

Temos que um repositório implementa parte das regras de negócio no que se refere à composição das entidades. Ele é fortemente **vinculado ao domínio da aplicação** e este é um reflexo direto das regras de negócio, pois **ele abstrai armazenamento e consulta de um ou mais entidades de domínio**.

Entretanto, não podemos confundir isso com as regras de negócio no sentido de processamento das informações. Um repositório não deve incluir as regras de negócio no sentido de tomar decisões, aplicar algoritmos de transformação dos dados ou prover serviços diretamente a outras camadas ou módulos da aplicação. Mapear entidades de domínio e prover as funcionalidades da aplicação são responsabilidades distintas.

Um repositório fica entre as regras de negócio e a camada de persistência:

1. Ele provê uma interface para as regras de negócio onde os objetos são acessados como em uma coleção.
2. Ele usa a camada de persistência para gravar e recuperar os dados necessários para persistir e recuperar os objetos de negócio.

Portanto um repositório pode, inclusive, fazer uso de um ou mais DAOs.

A interface de um repositório muitas vezes é análoga à interface de `List` do Java ou C#, provavelmente com a exceção dos métodos de pesquisa.

Exemplo:

```
interface ClienteRepository {
    void persistir(Cliente)
    Cliente recuperar(Integer)
    List<Cliente> pesquisar(TermosDaPesquisa)
    List<Cliente> todos()
}
```

No exemplo acima, num cenário mais simples, `ClienteRepository.persistir()` pode fazer uso do método `ClienteDao.incluir()`. Porém, ele pode também verificar se o cliente já existe e, neste caso, usar o método `ClienteDao.atualizar()`. Indo mais além, se `Cliente` é uma entidade de domínio mais complexa ele poderia carregar uma lista de endereços a partir de outro DAO.

Enfim, repositórios **não contém regras de negócio**, mas **contém** lógica para construir e persistir corretamente os objetos de domínio.

## Frameworks ORM

Frameworks como Hibernate (Java) ou NHibernate (.NET)disponibilizam uma interface bem mais próxima ao padrão *Repository* porque:

1. Trabalham com coleções. Vide métodos `persist()` e `find()`.
2. As pesquisas são realizadas por uma interface independente do tipo de banco de dados.
3. Realizam o trabalho de construir e armazenar as entidades da aplicação, inclusive com a possibilidade de recuperar valores de relações automaticamente, como no exemplo acima sobre a lista de endereços do cliente.

Além disso, eles também fazem o papel do DAO, pois:

- Armazenam dados diretamente num banco de dados.
- Geram as consultas SQL necessárias.
- Mapeiam os tipos de dados da fonte para um tipo adequado nos objetos e vice-versa.

Em contrapartida, é claro que tais frameworks sem sempre conseguem substituir completamente um repositório específico da aplicação por serem muito genéricos. Então, mesmo ao usar um ORM, pode ser interessante não misturar suas regras de negócio com código específico do framework. Neste caso, criar Repositórios que fazem uso do framework faz sentido, como se fosse um DAO++, afinal você está num maior nível de abstração e não está abstraindo o acesso à fonte de dados.

## Quando usar os padrões

O uso de DAOs é praticamente uma necessidade se você não usa ORMs, mesmo que você use outra nomenclatura, afinal você precisa de um lugar para colocar o código SQL.

Repositórios, por outro lado, são interessantes para aplicações um pouco maiores, onde o custo de adicionar mais uma camada de abstração é justificado pelo reuso em outros componentes, módulos e camadas.

Como já descrito acima, quando se trabalha com um ORM, faz sentido criar repositórios para abstrair o código específico do framework. O que não faz muito sentido (já vi isso por aí) é criar DAOs para abstrair o ORM, pois isso é forçar um pouco o conceito de DAO.

Repositórios também são bastante úteis para criar implementações alternativas para armazenamento. Como a interface é baseada em coleções, é fácil implementar uma versão do repositório usando uma lista em memória, artifício muito útil para execução de testes unitários ou de integração de forma independente do banco de dados.

## Onde eles se parecem

A confusão começa porque tanto DAO quanto Repository abstraem de alguma forma o acesso aos dados, embora, como vimos acima, eles tem níveis completamente diferentes de abstração.

Outro problema é que algumas das operações (métodos) de DAOs e Repositórios são comuns e, dependendo da implementação, não tem diferença alguma. Parte disso é pela implementação incorreta dos padrões. Outra parte é porque nem sempre é possível seguir o modelo em sua completude, por exemplo quando a abstração em forma de uma coleção penaliza o desempenho de tal forma que um repositório precisa implementar um método de mais baixo nível para tornar uma funcionalidade viável.

## Onde divergem

Um ponto importantíssimo para entender que a diferença não é apenas acidental é entender a origem dos padrões. Enquanto DAO foi pensado principalmente para abstrair fontes de dados genéricas, o contexto em que Repository foi concebido envolve DDD e pode ser usado com outros padrões específicos. ([fonte](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-repository-design-pattern--net-35804))

DAOs podem persistir e recuperar DTOs ou, em sistemas mais simples, das próprias entidades do sistema. Repositórios sempre fazem referência a uma entidade do domínio da aplicação. Claro que você pode estender o conceito para outras coisas, mas não deve ser a norma.

DAOs geralmente abstraem uma query no banco de dados. Repositórios pode necessitar de várias queries para compor uma entidade.

DAOs não gerenciam transações. Repositórios podem gerenciar ou pelo menos exigir a execução dentro de uma transação.

DAOs acessam diretamente a fonte de dados. Repositórios geralmente usam algum outro mecanismo para persistir dados, tal como um ORM ou os próprios DAOs.

Comment: obrigado pelo seu tempo e dedicação pela resposta, irei ler e avaliar com as demais, novamente, obrigado!

Comment: Excelente resposta! Quero fazer um complemento: embora a rigor não contenham em si nenhuma regra de negócio (há controvérsias mas de maneira geral esta afirmação não está incorreta), **os repositórios estão sim relacionados à regra de negócio**, pois o repositório conhece as entidades do domínio e suas agregações (como você mesmo descreveu), conhecendo as suas necessidades específicas de persistência e recuperação - principalmente tendo em mente a referência que você citou (Fowler), que por sua vez cita o DDD. Vou listar uns exemplos (1/3).

Comment: **a)** Uma entidade que antes fazia parte de um agregado ganhou mais responsabilidade, identificou-se para ela uma identidade global e ela passou a ser uma entidade raiz de seu próprio agregado. Se você usa repositórios você agora precisará de um novo para atender esta mudança nas regras de negócio, pois você tem uma nova entidade raiz. **b)** Se a forma de recuperar entidades com um certo estado mudar, você também precisará mudar o seu repositório. Nestes exemplos, vemos que o Repositório mudou em função de mudanças nas regras de negócio (mesmo sem nenhuma mudança nas tabelas do banco) (2/3)

Comment: Por fim, eu diria que o Hibernate está muito mais pra DAO do que pra Repositório, já que ele não conhece as necessidades e características específicas de um tipo de entidade mas sim as necessidades genéricas de ORM - não apenas do seu domínio mas também de qualquer outro domínio. A rigor, se cada repositório é especializado em um tipo de entidade ou agregação, não faria sentido uma interface genérica para todos os repositórios - já tive projetos em que alguns tipos de entidades tinham e muitos outros não tinham um "findById", por exemplo. (3/3)

Comment: @Caffé Muito obrigado pelas colocações. Eu revi pelo menos uns dois pontos da resposta. Acredito que a confusão ocorreu porque às vezes usamos o termo "regras de negócio" com conotações diferentes. Claro que o domínio é um reflexo de regras de negócio e, nesse sentido, os repositórios implementam essas regras. O que eu quis dizer (e espero que esteja mais claro agora) é que as funcionalidades da aplicação não devem ser implementadas em repositórios.

Comment: @Caffé Por outro lado eu não acho que o fato dos repositórios mudarem devido a mudanças no domínio seja uma prova de que eles implementam regras de negócio. Toda a aplicação deve ser construída com base nas regras de negócio. Se simplesmente incrementarmos o tamanho de um campo texto em um caractere haverá mudanças desde o banco de dados até o JavaScript de validação na tela. Só dei esse exemplo para mostrar porque eu geralmente não incluo o domínio ou algumas restrições nas "regra de negócio", embora eu reconheça que eu preciso empregar outro termo para fazer isso - só não sei qual exatamente

Comment: @Caffé Quando ao Hibernate, eu também atualizei a resposta. Acontece que ele cumpre o papel do DAO e tenta fazer o papel de um repositório tanto quanto possível. Para os casos mais comuns, você pode mapear as regras de negócio usando anotações e *named queries* de forma que você chegue a algo próximo do que você precisa, embora usando uma interface genérica. Claro que na maioria das aplicações sérias isso não é suficiente, então usa-se ele como um DAO++.

Comment: Você está certo, @utluiz, realmente não prova e ótima observação também sobre quando o Hibernate pode ser considerado repositório. É muito difícil expressar conceitos tão complexos em comentário ou mesmo nas respostas aqui no SO. É praticamente um milagre o tanto que a gente consegue se entender/aprender/ensinar sobre essas ideias neste formato :-)

Comment: @Caffé Nem diga. :)

Answer (score 17):

Me desculpe, mas o Repositório não deve estar associado a nenhuma regra de negócio. Tanto o DAO quanto o Repositório devem ser "burros".

Um Repositório é a classe responsável por todo acesso a dados de uma Entidade, ações como incluir, editar, apagar, e diversas consultas ficam no repositório.

Outras classes em uma camada acima dos repositórios ficam responsáveis pelas regras de negócio e consumir os repositórios para acessar os dados.

Normalmente quando utilizado com interfaces a utilização dos repositórios agiliza drasticamente a criação da camada de acesso a dados.

### Aqui um exemplo simples em C#:

Levando em consideração que você tem uma classe que herda de `DbContext` chamada `SuaClasseDbContext` (simplificando) desse jeito:

```cs
public class SuaClasseDbContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Autor> Autores {get; set;}
}
```

Essa interface diz todas as entidades devem ter um `Id`, que seria correspondente a chave primária:

```cs
public class IEntidade
{
   public long Id; 
}
```

Um repositório genérico, onde a interface de um repositório que aceita qualquer classe que implemente a interface `IEntidade` é definida com os método básicos:

```cs
public interface IRepositorio<T> where T: IEntidade
{
     void Adicionar(T entity);
     void Apagar(T entity);
     void Atualizar(T entity);
     void Salvar();
     T ObterPorId(int Id);
     IEnumerable<T> ObterTodos();
     IEnumerable<T> ObterPorFiltro(Expression<Func<T, bool>> filtro);
}
```

Em seguida uma classe que representa uma entidade em seu sistema, veja que ela implementa a interface `IEntidade`:

```cs
public class Autor : IEntidade
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Depois podemos criar o repositório implementando a interface definida:

```cs
public class AutorRepositorio : IRepositorio<Autor>
{
    private readonly SuaClasseDbContext dbContext;

    public AutorRepositorio(SuaClasseDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }
    
    public void Adicionar(Autor autor)
    {
        SuaClasseDbContext.Autores.Add(autor);
    }
    
    public void Apagar(Autor autor)
    {
        SuaClasseDbContext.Autores.Remove(autor);
    }
    
    public void Atualizar(Autor autor)
    {
            SuaClasseDbContext.Entry(autor).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public void Salvar()
    {
        SuaClasseDbContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    
    public Autor ObterPorId(int Id)
    {
        return SuaClasseDbContext.Autores.Find(Id);
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<Autor> ObterTodos()
    {
        return SuaClasseDbContext.Autores.ToList();
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<Autor> ObterPorFiltro(Expression<Func<Autor, bool>> filtro)
    {
        return SuaClasseDbContext.Autores.Where(filtro).ToList();
    }
}
```

Na hora de usar fica assim, um Console *Application*, por exemplo:

```cs
IRepositorio<Autor> repositorio = new AutorRepositorio();

// Regra de negócio responsável por consultar todos os autores que comecem
// com a letra A
// a regra de negócio está no consumo do repositório e não dentro dele
var resultado = repositorio.ObterPorFiltro(a => a.Nome.StartsWith("A"));
            
foreach (var autor in resultado)
{
   Console.WriteLine(autor.Nome);
 
}
```

Comment: **-1** Segundo sua resposta não existe diferença nenhuma entre os dois padrões. Mas mudo o voto no mesmo instante para **+1** se explicar a diferença com algum embasamento.

Comment: Acredito que você possa criar um insert num Repository, que de fato só persistirá dado uma condição seja verdadeira. Isso é regra de negócio. Então sua definição de Repository está mais pro DAO.

Comment: Oi utluiz, na verdade o conceito dos dois é o mesmo, por isso não existe diferença. No entanto um conceito pode ser implementado de várias formas, ai que o Repositorio e o DAO se diferenciam, por normalmente um Repositorio está associado a utilização de um ORM como o Entity Framework ou NHibernate (ambos para .net), e o DAO normalmente você gerenciar a conexão (abrindo e fechando), se preocupa em executar a instrução SQL que você mesmo escreveu, verifica se ela retornou dados, preenche a coleção, tudo na mão.

Comment: +1 De fato a resposta não deixa claro a diferença entre os dois, que é o foco da pergunta, mas pelo menos conceitua a coisa corretamente. Esta pode não ter falado em DAO, mas a mais votada não passar perto do que é o Repository. Mas ela faz pior, ela diz que é. Este é um caso clássico de votação errada, provavelmente porque a resposta ruim foi dada antes. pra falar a verdade a outra resposta só me confundiu.

Answer (score 3):

**Queries sql, jpaql, hql** ou que seja, estão relacionadas sim a regra de negócio, não diretamente e sim indiretamente.
Para que você possa extrair exatamente as informações de que precisa de qualquer `repositório de dados`, você precisa de um padrão para que essa extração seja feita, nos `sgbds` utilizamos consultas `sql`.

**Data access objects** são objetos destinados a abstrair a forma como são acessadas as informações necessárias para a execução das regras de negócio, seja através de um `sgbd, ldap, arquivo, filesystem` etc. se adiconarmos regras de consulta nesses objetos engessaremos eles a apenas garimpar dados que vão obedecer aquela regra.

**Repositories** são responsáveis por manipular essas informações já garimpadas/extraídas, seja utilizando as linguagens relacionadas acima ou uma outra técnica para o mesmo fim, é claro que não teremos regras de negócio explicitas nesses objetos em função de uma melhor manutenção e ou evolução (mesmo que a implementação da regra seja uma `query`) por esta razão nossos objetos de negócio farão uso desses "repositórios de dados" para que possam executar essas regras.

Um exemplo claro e bem pratico disso é a utilização de um mapeamento objeto relacional que pra facilitar o entendimento falemos do `jpa/hibernate`, onde as classes responsáveis por conterem as consultas `jpaql/hql` não são `DAOS` (levando em consideração a definição acima), muito menos objetos de negócio mas tem a responsabilidade de conterem os dados que precisamos pra aplicar uma ou mais regras.