# Posso utilizar os padrões de projeto DAO e Repository juntos?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software

Estou estudando persistência de dados em Java e me vieram esses dois padrões: DAO e  Repository.
Muitos falam que é melhor usar DAO, já outros que é melhor o Repository. Já alguns citam o uso de ambos no projeto.
Então pensei em utilizar o DAO na camada de infra, com o acesso direto ao banco e os repositórios na camada de negócios utilizando os DAO's e aplicando as regras de negócio.
Gostaria de saber a opinião de vocês a respeito dessa prática e sugestões de boas práticas com persistência de dados.

Comment: Resposta: Sim, pode. Quanto a opiniões, a gente tenta evitá-las e procuramos fundamentar as resposta com argumentos, demonstrações e referências. Seria legal se você pudesse dizer o que você entende por *DAO* e o que você entende por *Repository*. Você pode escrever aqui a sua definição ou apontar as referências que você está utilizando. Além disso, qual problema você quer resolver ou quais benefícios você espera destes patterns? Por enquanto eu só vejo aqui uma oportunidade para um bate-papo e não vejo muito potencial para oferecer uma boa resposta...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essa é uma pergunta interessante e creio que recorrente na Stack. Vou usar como linguagem java que tenho mais domínio, mas esta regra se aplica a qualquer linguagem, uma vez que estamos falando de Design de Software.

### DAO

Como quase resposta, você pode se basear na nesta outra resposta:

[Qual a diferença entre DAO e Repository?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12927/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-dao-e-repository)

> Um repositório está vinculado à regra de negócio da aplicação e está
>   associado ao agregado dos seus objetos de negócio e retorna objetos de
>   domínio que representam esses dados.
>
> ...
>
> Já o DAO (Data Access Object) a principio tem o seu escopo limitado na
>   captura e persistência dos dados de um objeto DTO (Data Transfer
>   Object) que representa um registro da base de dados, consequentemente
>   ele transmite apenas o mundo físico relacional da base de dados e não
>   representa o mini-mundo real do negócio da sua aplicação.

O que eu não acho que foi muito coerente, foi a explicação pratica dela. O mundo perfeito do DAO deveria ser propriamente as operacoes básicas que precisamos para manusear os dados (independente do fornecedor ser um banco de dados relacional, arquivo ou qualquer outra coisa que possa manter um estado):

- **recuperarPorIdentificador**
- **adicionar**
- **remover**
- **atualizar**
- **listar** (algumas pessoas acham este método desnecessario, pois seria o mesmo que um pesquisar sem um filtro de pesquisa)
- **listar** com um filtroDePesquisa(que é um parâmetro, geralmente conhecido como "Query Object")

### Repository

Este, propiamente representa os dados que o negócio necessita obter. Faremos a requisição deles para o DAO.

Geralmente possui os mesmo métodos básicos do DAO (não é uma regra, você poderia limitar a visão no seu software apenas à aqueles métodos que são chamados diretamente pela camada de negócio, que geralmente é nomeada com **Service**):

- **recuperarPorIdentificador**
- **adicionar**
- **remover**
- **atualizar**
- **listar**
- **listar** com um filtroDePesquisa

e os métodos que seu negócio costuma precisar para obter dados filtrados:

- **listarUsuariosAtivos**

> ```
> UsuarioFilter usuarioFilter = new UsuarioFilter();
> usuarioFilter.setAtivo(true);
>
> List<Usuario> usuariosAtivos = usuarioDAO.listar(usuarioFilter);
> ```

- **obterUltimoUsuarioCadastrado**

> ```
> UsuarioFilter usuarioFilter = new UsuarioFilter();
> usuarioFilter.getOrdersBy().add(UsuarioFilter.OrderBy.DATA_CADASTRO_DESC);
> usuarioFilter.setLimit(1);
>
> List<Usuario> usuarios = usuarioDAO.listar(usuarioFilter);
> Usuario ultimoUsuarioCadastrado = usuarios.isEmpty() ? null : usuarios.iterator().next(); // ou usuarios.get(0);
> ```

O cenário recomendado é Service -> Repository -> DAO

[Aqui tem um link para uma explicação mais detalhada](https://visola.github.io/2012/11/12/dao-repository-and-service-digging-deeper/) se precisar.

### Referências importantes

- [Identify Field](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/identityField.html)
- [Repository](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

Comment: Qual a vantagem de ter os dois padrões juntos e não apenas Repository por exemplo?

Comment: A principal vantagem é a coesão de camadas. Repository é a camada responsável por fornecer dados para sua camada de negócio que não sabe como esses dados são mantidos. Quem deveria ser responsável pela manipulação deles, deveria ser o DAO. Quando você faz Service -> DAO, provavelmente terá um DAO com muitas linhas de código, muitas vezes repetitivas. Caso você mude a forma de persistencia, pode ser que o refactory seja bem mais trabalhoso do que se tivesse usado Service - > Repository -> DAO.