# Dúvida validação de cpf antes de inserir no banco

Tags: java

Na minha classe `SocioDAO` eu tenho o metodo `salvarSocio()` que irá salvar no banco de dados. Na minha classe `DadosUsuario` eu tenho as informações que precisam ser gravadas
no banco no caso `cadastrarUsuario()`. Como proceder para validar CPF?

Não queria colocar a validação dentro do meu método `cadastrarUsuario()` pois não o mesmo não deveria ficar muito grande.

```
public class SocioDAO {

    public void salvarSocio(Socio socio) throws SQLException {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("INSERT INTO socio ");
        sql.append("(nome, telefone, ddd, email, cpf) ");
        sql.append("VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

        Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();

        PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

        comando.setString(1, socio.getNome());
        comando.setInt(2, socio.getTelefone());
        comando.setInt(3, socio.getDdd());
        comando.setString(4, socio.getEmail());
        comando.setString(5, socio.getCpf());

        comando.executeUpdate();

    }



public class DadosUsuario {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void cadastrarUsuario() {

        Socio cadastrarUser = new Socio();

        System.out.println("Informe um nome: ");
        cadastrarUser.setNome(scan.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Informe um telefone: ");
        cadastrarUser.setTelefone(scan.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Informe o DDD: ");
        cadastrarUser.setDdd(scan.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Informe o email: ");
        cadastrarUser.setEmail(scan.next());

        System.out.println("Informe o cpf: ");
        cadastrarUser.setCpf(scan.next());

        SocioDAO dao = new SocioDAO();

        try {
            dao.salvarSocio(cadastrarUser);
            System.out.println("USUÁRIO CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERRO AO CADASTRAR USUÁRIO.");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Já que você não tem uma camada de negócio e acessa o DAO diretamente, você deveria colocar a validação dentro do DAO, que encontrando algum problema, lançar uma excecao. Colocando dentro do DAO, qualquer lugar que você venha a instanciar ele, garantirá que o dado estará sendo validado.

Em uma aplicação mais séria, nunca acessamos o DAO diretamente. Sempre passamos por uma camada de negócio que serve justamente para fazer esta validação, ficando Service (com sua regra de negócio e validação) -> DAO

[Aproveite para dar uma olhada nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/59080/posso-utilizar-os-padr%C3%B5es-de-projeto-dao-e-repository-juntos/59380#59380) também, o assunto pode ser bem longo.

**edit**: exemplo simples com camada de negócio

```
public class SocioService { // Tem pessoas que preferem SocioBusiness

    private SocioDAO socioDAO;

    public SocioService() {
        socioDAO = new SocioDAO();
    }

    public void inserir(Socio socio) throws ServiceException { // inserir ou adicionar deixa claro que é "criação" de registro.

        if (socio.getNome() == null || socio.getNome().trim().length()) {
            throw new ServiceException("Nome não pode estar vazio");
        }

        // ... outras validacoes

        socioDAO.salvarSocio(socio); // cuidado com o adjetivo salvar, ele pode deixar a pessoa que chama em duvida, se estiver trabalhando em equipe, a pessoa iria querer ver o fonte para saber se aqui está sendo inserido ou atualizando um registro.
    }
}

public class ServiceException extends Exception {

    public ServiceException(String mensagem) {
        super(mensagem);
    }
}
```

Comment: E como eu poderia criar essa outra camada... Poderia me dar um toque?

Comment: embora não seja o escopo da sua pergunta, adicionei. Se você não tem também como se recuperar de uma SQLException, crie uma exceção de runtime (não checada) sua, e lance-a de dentro do DAO. Tem outros detalhes importantes também de como não manipular transacoes dentro de um método do DAO, mas agora não vem ao caso :o)