# Como criar Exception

Tags: java

Estou tentando fazer um Exception porem não estou conseguindo. Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para resolver esse problema. estou desde ontem tentando validar um campo mas esta difícil... Desde já agradeço a todos! No caso esse campo seria nome caso ele fosse nulo!

```
public class SocioDAO {

public void salvarSocio(Socio socio) throws SQLException {
    StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
    sql.append("INSERT INTO socio ");
    sql.append("(nome, telefone, ddd, email, cpf) ");
    sql.append("VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

    Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();

    PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

    comando.setString(1, socio.getNome());
    comando.setInt(2, socio.getTelefone());
    comando.setInt(3, socio.getDdd());
    comando.setString(4, socio.getEmail());
    comando.setString(5, socio.getCpf());

    comando.executeUpdate();

}
```

---

```
public class Socio {

private Long codigo;
private String nome;
private Integer telefone;
private Integer ddd;
private String email;
private String cpf;

public Long getCodigo() {
    return codigo;
}

public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
    this.codigo = codigo;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public Integer getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(Integer telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

public Integer getDdd() {
    return ddd;
}

public void setDdd(Integer ddd) {
    this.ddd = ddd;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getCpf() {
    return cpf;
}

public void setCpf(String cpf) {
    this.cpf = cpf;
}
```

---

```
public class DadosUsuario {

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

public void cadastrarUsuario() {

    Socio cadastrarUser = new Socio();

    System.out.println("Informe um nome: ");
    cadastrarUser.setNome(scan.nextLine());

    System.out.println("Informe um telefone: ");
    cadastrarUser.setTelefone(scan.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Informe o DDD: ");
    cadastrarUser.setDdd(scan.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Informe o email: ");
    cadastrarUser.setEmail(scan.next());

    System.out.println("Informe o cpf: ");
    cadastrarUser.setCpf(scan.next());



    SocioDAO dao = new SocioDAO();
    try {
        dao.salvarSocio(cadastrarUser);
        System.out.println("USUÁRIO CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("ERRO AO CADASTRAR USUÁRIO.");
        //e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Você leu com calma a resposta que coloquei na sua pergunta ontem ? Lá tem a resposta para este pergunta. Se houver dúvidas, me avise. Pergunta original: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63765/d%C3%BAvida-valida%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-cpf-antes-de-inserir-no-banco

Answer (score 0):

Se você tem a certeza que o que quer é lançar uma *Exception* então aqui vai.

No método `setNome` da classe *Socio* teste o valor passado.

```
public void setNome(String nome) {
    if(nome == null || nome == ""){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tem de indicar um nome");
    }
    this.nome = nome;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

inclua o `import java.sql.SQLException`

Veja mais aqui. -> http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-exceptions.htm

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a resposta? podes trazer para aqui algum conteudo desse link para a resposta ficar mais completa. Não fui eu que dei `-1` mas respostas pouco explicadas atraem votos negativos.