# Dúvida sobre distribuição de dados entre classes

Tags: java, jdbc

Eu tenho uma classe chamada `Socio` que pede o nome, telefone... e eu criei métodos *getters* e *setters*. E uma outra classe chamada `DadosDoUsuario` que irá pedir as informações para preencher o cadastro, mas o que acontece é que nessa classe `DadosDoUsuario` está recebendo informações do usuário e inserindo no banco.

Eu gostaria de fazer uma outra classe `InsereNoBanco` recebendo os dados digitados pelo usuário... Ou seja, a classe `DadosDoUsuario` só iria receber as informações e passar para a classe `InsereNoBanco`. Vocês poderiam me dar algumas dicas, pois já tentei de todas as formas e está complicado. Desde já agradeço a todos. Obrigado!

```java
public class Socio {

    private Long codigo;
    private String nome;
    private Integer telefone;
    private Integer ddd;
    private String email;
    private String cpf;

    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) throws NomeUsuarioNaoInformado {
        if (nome.equals(null) || nome.equals("")) {
            throw new NomeUsuarioNaoInformado();
        }

        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Integer getTelefone() {
        return telefone;
    }

    public void setTelefone(Integer telefone) {
        this.telefone = telefone;
    }

    public Integer getDdd() {
        return ddd;
    }

    public void setDdd(Integer ddd) {
        this.ddd = ddd;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }
}
```

```java
public class DadosUsuario {

    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void cadastrarUsuario() throws NomeUsuarioNaoInformado {

        Socio cadastrarUser = new Socio();

        System.out.println("Informe um nome: ");
        cadastrarUser.setNome(scan.nextLine());

        System.out.println("Informe um telefone: ");
        cadastrarUser.setTelefone(scan.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Informe o DDD: ");
        cadastrarUser.setDdd(scan.nextInt());

        System.out.println("Informe o email: ");
        cadastrarUser.setEmail(scan.next());

        System.out.println("Informe o cpf: ");
        cadastrarUser.setCpf(scan.next());

        SocioDAO dao = new SocioDAO();
        try {
            dao.salvarSocio(cadastrarUser);
            System.out.println("USUÁRIO CADASTRADO COM SUCESSO.");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("ERRO AO CADASTRAR USUÁRIO.");
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public class SocioDAO {

    public void salvarSocio(Socio socio) throws SQLException {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("INSERT INTO socio ");
        sql.append("(nome, telefone, ddd, email, cpf) ");
        sql.append("VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

        Connection conexao = ConexaoFactory.conectar();

        PreparedStatement comando = conexao.prepareStatement(sql.toString());

        comando.setString(1, socio.getNome());
        comando.setInt(2, socio.getTelefone());
        comando.setInt(3, socio.getDdd());
        comando.setString(4, socio.getEmail());
        comando.setString(5, socio.getCpf());

        comando.executeUpdate();

    }
}
```

Comment: Não consigo entender qual seria a finalidade da classe `InsereNoBanco`. Ela me parece que seria um `DAO`, mas você já tem um `DAO` e já está utilizando-o.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/63765/132

Comment: É para fazer programação em camadas e estou tendo dificuldades para entender isso... Então queria criar mais classe Dao só para receber a s informações e não para receber as informações digitadas pelo usuário e inserir ao banco ao mesmo tempo.... entendeu?

Comment: A classe *DadosUsuario* está obtendo as entradas do usuário e a classe "SocioDAO" está inserindo estes dados no banco. Você pode dizer que *Socio* pertence à camada *Negócios* ou *Domínio*, *DadosUsuario* pertence à camada *Aplicação* e *SocioDAO* pertence à camada *Infra*. Os nomes podem ser melhorados, mas o seu código já está bem dividido em camadas. O que em particular você não gostou no seu código?

Comment: Blz... É que o professor disse para dar uma melhorada... Mas, eu achei tbm que estava bem distribuído, enfim... Valeu... Achei que estivesse fora do padrão pedido... OBRIGADO...