# Como otimizar o acesso ao Banco de Dados?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Estou fazendo um projeto onde em muitas vezes preciso acessar o Banco de Dados para fazer coisas como:

- Carregar dados do Usuário (Exemplo: Saldo, Configurações);
- Carregar imagens;
- Inserir/Atualizar dados.

É um processo bem chato ter que fazer o mesmo código várias vezes e só mudar a SQL, ou a Tabela.

Decidi fazer uma classe de Conexão, porém dentro dessa classe só guardo a **ConnectionString**, acaba não mudando muita coisa.

```
public class DBConnection
{
     public const string ConnectionString = @"....";   
}
```

Eu herdo essa classe em todas as classes que preciso acessar o Banco de Dados, com esse código abaixo eu atualizo o Saldo do usuário.

```
using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblClientes SET Saldo += @Saldo WHERE Usuário = @Usuário", sqlConnection))
{
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Saldo", SqlDbType.Real).Value = Saldo;
    sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Usuário", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = Usuario;

    sqlConnection.Open();
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

- Como posso otimizar isso?
- Para que eu não precise repetir esse mesmo código várias vezes no meu projeto?

Comment: Tem várias abordagens que você pode seguir: você pode procurar por algum padrão de projeto que te ajude a abstrair essa parte toda como [DAO](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113840/como-funciona-o-padr%C3%A3o-dao), ou um [padrão de repositórios](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/12927/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-dao-e-repository). Você pode também procurar por um ORM como o [Entity Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/), o [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) ou o [NHibernate](https://nhibernate.info/).

Comment: Ao que tudo indica, você precisa mesmo é de um ORM como o Entity Framework.

Comment: Vou pesquisar sobre o assunto, obrigado!!

Comment: Seguindo o conselho do @LINQ concentre no padrão de repositório e procure entender realmente como ele funciona e como implementá-lo, esse é a base para as outras dicas que ele deu. E não necessariamente você precisa de um ORM, pois muito da otimização ainda vai envolver questões no banco de dados como revisão das queries e criação de índices.

Comment: Um framework ajuda a padronizar, claro para esse ambiente é o que tem já "semi-pronto", mas uma coisa simples que pode ser aplicado em qualquer lugar, seria criar um método que recebe como primeiro parametro uma string, essa string seria a query, e dentro do método tem o processo de conexão e comando. Pronto, não precisaria ficar repetindo código assim ... Eu entendo perfeitamente quererem ensinar frameworks e sistemas prontos, mas algo básico e até trivial como evitar a repetição de código com um simples método é algo que deve ser aprendido antes de ir para o mais **glamuroso**

Comment: Eu tinha pensando em criar métodos para cada função a se executar no Banco de Dados, como Select, Update, Delete, etc. No construtor da classe eu receberia a Query e nos métodos eu receberia um array de parâmetros, que no caso é os que estariam na Query, acha isso uma boa ideia @GuilhermeNascimento?

Comment: @HenriqueFerreira acho q só um método resolve, não adianta enfeitar muito, ainda mais se tiver queries "compostas" (tipo sub-query ou uso de JOIN). Dá pra jogar tudo na string, não pense q vai criar isso para usar para sempre, tem que criar para resolver o agora, mas claro, bem feito e simples, o resto vem com o tempo, pratica e expericia que será adquirida, por isso sempre apoio o simples, ao invés de empurrar frameworks complexos para as pessoas, o bom é partir do básico :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Entendi, dependendo do que quero executar o código fica diferente, então querendo ou não vou precisar de mais de um método. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Não vi Herança (`Eu herdo essa classe em todas as classes que preciso acessar o Banco de Dados, com esse código abaixo eu atualizo o Saldo do usuário.`) pelo seu comentário, vai depender bastante, no seu caso que é um Windows Forms, eu utilizaria `singleton` na classe de conexão e criaria classes `DAL`( Camada de Acesso a Dados) para fazer as operações no Banco. Ou então, Dapper e Entity Framework, onde o micro orm (DAPPER) para SQL complexas que vão exigir desempenho e Entity Framework (ORM) para inserção, remover e updates diversos. Vale lembrar que o cenário não exposto por você conta muito

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Não viu porque eu não mostrei isso na classe Saldo, mas basicamente o que herdo é só a classe DBConnection para usar a ConnectionString.

Comment: @HenriqueFerreira inclusive talvez isso seja um problema! não pode herdar assim, tem que analisar bem, eu faria uma classe de conexão singleton não somente com a conection string, mas, sim com um command e outra estruturas já preparadas para usar, ou então vai de Dapper.